# Suddenly no WIFI and network service is down

Tags: centos, wifi, network-interface

I installed Centos 7 64bit on my Lenovo laptop and KDE for a while every thing was just great!
Last night I was trying to make Dolphin show video thumbnails and it toke some Time but I managed to do it unfortunately when I restarted the laptop there was no wifi!
I did update the system (sudo yum update) and installed some packages for the ffmpeg but nothing more and now (network) service is down and can not be started
Also when I tried "nmtui" there was no wifi connection at all!

Here are some output for the commands I thought may help understand

```
# lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188CE 802.11b/g/n WiFi Adapter [10ec:8176] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8195]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192ce
--
0c:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:21f7]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

and

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp12s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:97:0e:dd:c7:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp6s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:f0:2f:7a:1a:80 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:66:cf:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: virbr0-nic: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN mode DEFAULT qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:66:cf:5e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and

```
# systemctl status network.service
● network.service - LSB: Bring up/down networking
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/network; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-10-25 10:57:25 EET; 24s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 2477 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/network start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain network[2477]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain network[2477]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain network[2477]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain network[2477]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain network[2477]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain network[2477]: RTNETLINK answers: File exists
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit network.service entered failed state.
Oct 25 10:57:25 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: network.service failed.
```

And finally

```
# systemctl start network
    Job for network.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status network.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.


 network-scripts]# ls
ifcfg-enp12s0       ifdown-eth   ifdown-post    ifdown-TeamPort  ifup-eth   ifup-plip    ifup-sit       init.ipv6-global
ifcfg-lo            ifdown-ib    ifdown-ppp     ifdown-tunnel    ifup-ib    ifup-plusb   ifup-Team      keys-orange-admin
ifcfg-orange-admin  ifdown-ippp  ifdown-routes  ifup             ifup-ippp  ifup-post    ifup-TeamPort  network-functions
ifdown              ifdown-ipv6  ifdown-sit     ifup-aliases     ifup-ipv6  ifup-ppp     ifup-tunnel    network-functions-ipv6
ifdown-bnep         ifdown-isdn  ifdown-Team    ifup-bnep        ifup-isdn  ifup-routes  ifup-wireless
```

Comment: What do you have in your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` directory? Share also the content for the files related to your network interfaces there.

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager`
instead

Comment: I added the contents of network-scripts

Comment: What's the content of `ifcfg-enp12s0`?